# 10 bit values in a 16 bit image

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap

I am using C# to call a camera API in C++ which returns an image where each pixel is interpreted as a 2 byte value. However, the camera operates at 10 bits, so the image range is between 0 and 1023 inclusive.

For the usual 8 bit images, I was doing:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
ColorPalette ncp = bmp.Palette;
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    ncp.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(255, i, i, i);
bmp.Palette = ncp;
```

Now, I want to similarly create the palette entries for my 10 bit images. My question is whether I should use 1024 entries or the full 16 bit 65536 entries even though my range will always be 0-1023.

Comment: I don't know image formats with a palette of 1024 colors... I guess the safest way is indeed to use PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565

Comment: Actually I found out that `Format16bppGrayscale` does not really work with GDI+ drawing functions... I will need to probably convert it to a 48 bit RGB image :/

Comment: I suspect you mean each pixel has 10 bits per RGB channel, = 30 bits per pixel - is that correct?

Comment: The range is 10 bit but I convert it to an unsigned short. So each pixel is a 16 bit unsigned short grayscale image. However, the full range is not 0-65535 but 0-1023 if that makes sense.

Comment: First question you _need_ to answer before any of this can work: are the colours 1024-entry indexed, or do those 10 bit values _contain_ actual RGB colours? Because if it's indeed some odd 1024-colour paletted format you're probably going to need to read the raw bytes and get that palette out somehow, because no image format I know supports >256 colour palettes.