# 10/11/12 bit coded pixels in WPF

Tags: wpf, pixel

I need to use a mono-chromatic camera API which states in its manual the following:

> Each pixel (10, 11 or 12 bits) is coded on 16 bits. Pixel value is
> placed on the LSB of the 16 bits.

I will use WPF/C# with Bitmap; or I might use WPF with OpenGL. I don't have expertise in any.

Is the only way to down convert the pixels to 8-bit?([here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0cc9ca96-1f94-400f-a964-a5f77bf01c43/what-can-i-do-for-12bit-bit-gray-scale-image-conversion-in-wpf?forum=wpf) someone mentions)

I came across the closest question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029792/10-bit-values-in-a-16-bit-image) but with no answers.

Comment: There is also [PixelFormats.Gray16](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.pixelformats.gray16?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-media-pixelformats-gray16). You may shift the pixel bits by 6, 5 or 4 places to the left, which means multiplying them by 64, 32 or 16.

Comment: This sounds interesting. Could you write it as an answer with a short example for 10-bits or any bits you like? I have been spending days to find a solution.

Comment: If you show us how you data looks like... And tell us whether you want to create a single BitmapSource once from the raw data, or perhaps cyclically overwrite the buffer of a previously created WriteableBitmap. Maybe first try something yourself.

Comment: I think your answer is already adequate for what I was asking. I tried it and works fine. The only thing after some decimals numbers differ. For instance For 111: 12-bit gives 7/(1204 -1)  and 16-bit gives 448/(65536 -1). And the results are 0,00684261974584555 and  0,00683604180972. I hope I dint do any mistake.

Comment: So the error is always around 0,00095474044336. I guess not noticeable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a BitmapSource with `Format` set to `PixelFormats.Gray16`.

Then convert the source pixel values to 16-bit pixel values like this:

```
public static int ConvertTo16Bit(int pixelValue, int sourceBitsPerPixel)
{
    const int maxTargetValue = (1 << 16) - 1;
    int maxSourceValue = (1 << sourceBitsPerPixel) - 1;

    return maxTargetValue * pixelValue / maxSourceValue;
}
```

Convert pixel buffer arrays like this:

```
public static void ConverTo16Bit(
    ushort[] target, ushort[] source, int sourceBitsPerPixel)
{
    const int maxTargetValue = (1 << 16) - 1;
    int maxSourceValue = (1 << sourceBitsPerPixel) - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        target[i] = (ushort)(maxTargetValue * source[i] / maxSourceValue);
    }
}
```

Or when you want to create a new target pixel buffer, like this:

```
public static ushort[] ConverTo16Bit(ushort[] source, int sourceBitsPerPixel)
{
    const int maxTargetValue = (1 << 16) - 1;
    int maxSourceValue = (1 << sourceBitsPerPixel) - 1;

    return source
        .Select(value => (ushort)(maxTargetValue * value / maxSourceValue))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: This is really great answer. Exactly I was looking for. One more thing if you dont mind. If I have an array to convert do you recommend to use this function in a for loop and convert each one by one or should I make a class with an enum? To make conversion of arrays faster I mean. Thanks!

Comment: No idea what "class with enum" should be here, but you will of course have to call this method for each pixel in a loop. Maybe for efficiency pass maxSourceValue as argument instead of sourceBitsPerPixel.

Comment: Effectively, you have to call e.g. `target[i] = 65535 * source[i] / 1023` for 10-bit in a loop. Since target and source may be `ushort[]`, write `target[i] = (ushort)(65535 * (int)source[i] / 1023)`